# How to write an undergraduate level paper on topics of multilinear algebra or tensor?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, multilinear-algebra

I'm a undergraduate student majoring in Mathematics. My professor only suggested me considering the topics in multilinear algebra or tensor, but without any other specific instruction. This topic is so huge and I don't want to just copy down what the textbooks write.

Could anyone give me some advice? Is there any interesting little topic in this area?